# iOS Facebook FQL problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, cocoa

I'm trying to get the follow FQL statement working in my iOS app

```
SELECT comment_info,likes,share_count FROM stream WHERE post_id
```

For some reason i keep getting an error from the graph API saying

> Parse error: unexpected '?' at position 70 OAuth exception

The position moves so for some reason a '?' is being added on to the end of my SLRequests? Here is the block of code i am using. Driving me crazy now as i've tried a number of things and still can't get rid of this but works fine when pulling /me/home using the same method.

```
        NSLog(@"ID: %@", graphID);

        NSString* urlText = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT comment_info,likes,share_count FROM stream WHERE post_id = '%@'", graphID];
        urlText = [urlText stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlText];

        SLRequest * request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:url parameters: nil];
        request.account = self.facebookAccount;

        [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"url %@", request.URL.absoluteURL);
            NSString * responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSError* responseError;

            NSDictionary* jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:kNilOptions error:&responseError];
            NSArray * dataArray = jsonDict[@"data"];

            [dataArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary * infoDictionary, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                NSNumber *likesCount;
                NSNumber *commentsCount;

                likesCount = [NSNumber numberWithInt: [infoDictionary[@"likes"][@"count"] integerValue]];
                commentsCount = [NSNumber numberWithInt: [infoDictionary[@"comment_info"][@"comment_count"] integerValue]];

                NSLog(@"likes %@", likesCount);
            }];
        }];
```

Comment: Also there is no '?' showing in NSLog(@"url %@", request.URL.absoluteURL);

Answer (score 1):

This is the right approach

```
NSString* urlString = @"https://graph.facebook.com/fql";
urlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString* query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE post_id='%@' AND user_id=me()", postId];
SLRequest* request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                        requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                  URL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
                                           parameters:@{@"q" : query}];

request.account = <account>;
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use NSDictionary with 'q' parameter like this

```
NSDictionary *params = @{ @"q" : [NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT comment_info,likes,share_count FROM stream WHERE post_id = '%@'", graphID] };
```

and send it as params on your SLRequest.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

NSString* urlString = @"https://graph.facebook.com/fql";

urlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString* query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT comment_info,likes,share_count FROM stream WHERE post_id = '%@'", graphID];

SLRequest* request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                            requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                      URL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
                                               parameters:@{@"q" : query}];

```
request.account=self.facebookAccount;
[request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *data, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error)

 {
     if(!error)
     {

         NSDictionary *list =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        NSLog(@data from facebook : %@“,list);
     }
     else
     {

         NSLog(@"error while fetching data from facebook : %@",error);
     }


 }];
```